# Find Duplicates Records and show as one record if amount field varies from + 10 or -10 between records

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table where I have duplicate records. I want to find the duplicate records and show as one record for those values which have

> amounts values between -$10- to +$10.

```
>     For example 
>    ''' <Crate table test (
>             test_name VARCHAR2(100),
>             Test_color VARCHAR2(20), 
>             test_amt number (10,2)
>     ); 
>     insert into test values ('Apple','Red', 1234.00);
>     insert into test values ('Apple','Red', 1235.78);
>     insert into test values ('Apple','Red', 5235.78);
>     insert into test values ('Banana','Yellow', 7542.97);
>     insert into test values ('Banana','Yellow', 7542.97);
>     insert into test values ('Banana','Yellow', 9639.97);
>     insert into test values ('Banana','Yellow', 9640.00);
>     insert into test values ('Orange','Orange', 4573.00);
>     insert into test values ('Orange','Orange', 4574.28);
>     insert into test values ('Orange','Orange', 4573.18);
>  '''
```

> ```
> and I want output as below. 
>
> TEST_NAME   TEST_COLOR  TEST_AMT                             total_COUNT
> Apple           Red             1234.01                         2
> Apple           Red                 5235.78                     1
> Banana          Yellow            7542.97                       2
> Banana          Yellow          9639.97                         2
> Orange          Orange         4573                             3
> ```

Comment: What do you want to get in case of 100 rows with sequential ordered numbers 10,20,30,40...,980,990,1000? Ie each of them +10 from previous .Should it be returned as just one row?

Answer (score 1):

This is the perfect job for match_recognize.

And below is one way to do it:

```
select  test_name, test_color, test_amt, total_count    
from    test
match_recognize
(   
    partition by test_name
    order by test_amt
    measures final count(*) as total_count
    all rows per match
    pattern (a {- b* -} )
    define  b as b.test_amt <= a.test_amt + 10 
)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thank You Very Much for help me out. Appreciate for your help and support Sir.

Comment: Glad I could help you. Kindly mark my reply as the answer so that it might helps others having a similar scenario in the future.